# How should I add quote to it which match using python re?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, like this:

```
{"content":(uint64)123456, "id":(uint32)0}
```

**Note:**

this example string is simple, the real string is JSON except `(uint32)0` is not standard.

Now I need to transform it like this:

```
{"content":"(uint64)123456", "id":"(uint32)0"}
```

so, I write transform code with python re:

```
def format():
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\(uint32\)|\(int32\)|\(uint64\)|\(int64\))(\d)+')
    print pattern.sub('\"test\"', '{"content":(uint64)123456, "id":(uint32)0}')
```

How I should write code in `sub` function in order to tansform it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a string, `sub` function can accept also a callable as replacement.

So, instead of:

```
pattern.sub('\"test\"', s)
```

Make a function:

```
def add_quotes(match):
    return '"%s"' % match.group(0)

pattern.sub(add_quotes, s)
```